# C# + Linq program randomly just disappears

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I wrote a program that uses Linq to talk to an microsoft sql server. It runs nonstop and from time to time does some changes to the db, mostly at midnight. This works. But after a few days the process randomly just disappears. There is no excpetion window or an entry in the system event logs.

Now, I "fixed" it somehow. What I did: I just reconnect to the sql server every time it does some changes.

The sql server uns on the same machine btw. and there are other programs running using that sql server. So it can't be down or something like that. Besides, I'ld expect an exception in that case.

Just in case it's important: There are other clients using that same database.

How is it possible a .net app can just disappear? Shouldn't it throw exceptions? And even if it uses some native code, which this process does not, wouldn't there be a message like "windows terminated this process because of xxxxx"?

Comment: It sounds like the process finished executing. Perhaps it lost the connection to the database and followed some logic that told it to shutdown in that case. Is there anything like that in your code?

Comment: Or an exception is being caught and tossed or outputted in a fashion that isn't logged.

Comment: Show some code. Unless you have zero exit points (aka `while(true) { ... }`) without a generic `catch`, there should be some exception with the exception if the process got killed. Also, is this a console app? If so, add some liberal logging. `Debugger.Break()` is also handy if you have extra exit points.

Comment: No, not that I know of. It's also happening randomly, sometimes, it runs for 4 days, sometimes it disappears after 0.5 day. I also overloaded the onclosing method to prevent the window from accidentally being closed by someone. I think it has to do with linq somehow. I write my own log file and it happens when the conenction hasn't been used for some time and then it tries to do a linq query. That's why I tried reconnecting before the queries and somehow it "works".

Comment: Btw. I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594522/how-to-troubleshoot-net-application-that-just-disappears . I'm not using Crystal Reports though. The process just consists of a wpf window and some linq queries. 100-200 lines of code max.

Comment: @marc40000: Is it possible to reproduce the exit under the debugger?

Comment: @leppie: I haven't encountered this issue on my development machine. Now it's running on a server with no development tools installed. Then again, I haven't tested running it for multiple days on my dev machine.

Comment: @marc40000: I suggest you try that. At least you will either get it breaking on an exception or give you an exit code. If not possible with VS on the actual 'production' machine, you can use mdbg to launch the process. Just copy the 2-3 mdbg assemblies into the app dir and run launch the app from it. mdbg is a wonderful offsite debugging tool :)

Comment: Can you provide a link to your code so we can see what's going on? Someone might be able to spot something.

Comment: @SamuelSlade : I didn't expect anybody to want to look at the code since I don't know where the issue is located exactly and it's still more then 10 lines. But ok, I pasted together the relevant parts: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/103286/temp/mmserverpart.txt :)

Answer (score 4):

> How is it possible a .net app can just disappear?

One of three things happened: The program terminated normally, the program terminated itself abnormally (via an exception or a failfast), or some other process terminated the process.

> Shouldn't it throw exceptions?

I don't understand the question.

> And even if it uses some native code, which this process does not, wouldn't there be a message like "windows terminated this process because of xxxxx"?

Well, first off, it might not be Windows terminating the process. For example, perhaps someone attached a debugger to the process and then instructed the debugger to terminate the process.

Some applications are noisy when they terminate abnormally, and some are not -- in particular, applications which terminate with a failfast by definition do not spend time *terminating slowly* -- writing to logs and letting you know what happened, and so on. That's because they're terminating *as fast as possible*.

> Now, I "fixed" it somehow. What I did: I just reconnect to the sql server every time it does some changes

Were I in that situation I'd prefer to fix the problem by *understanding the problem* before I try to fix it.

Comment: Isn't there a 4th option, Windows terminated the process? I seem to recall that Windows will terminate your process on a double fault (i.e. processing an exception triggers another exception).

Comment: @Gabe: You are thinking of the behaviour exhibited by double faulting the stack. When the final guard page on the stack is hit, it triggers an out-of-stack exception, and moves itself into a "destroy the process if I am hit again" state. If it is hit again, the process fails fast. Whether you consider that to be an act of "Windows" or the process destroying itself is I suppose a bit of a philosophical question; from my perspective, it's just a *fact*: if you hit the guard page twice then the process fails fast. Who *does" the fail fast isn't relevant.

Comment: @"I don't understand the question": I was wondering how it is possible that a managed process can disappear silently. If something goes wrong, shouldn't it always throw an exception?

Comment: Why does it allow one out-of-stack excpetion and only terminates after the 2nd? Is it possible to generate this situation from managed c# code alone?

Comment: I made the distinction here because it seems like a good candidate for the OP's problem.

Comment: @marc40000: Maybe nothing went wrong -- maybe it terminated normally. Or maybe it terminated abnormally without an exception. There's no requirement that an abnormal termination have an exception associated with it. When you attach a debugger to a process and instruct the debugger to take down the process, there's no exception but that's certainly not a normal termination.

Comment: @marc40000: Double faults probably aren't your problem, but as an FYI: The first exception is a great chance to start debugging or otherwise diagnosing the problem.  The second exception is an indication that your exception handler threw an exception while handling your exception (maybe your kernel stack was blown).  See volume 3 of the [IA32 developer's guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html).

Comment: @marc40000: re: why? Well, what would be preferrable? Surely you don't want it to fail fast when you run out of stack on the *first* hit to the guard page? Re: is this possible in C#? Now that I think about it a bit more, maybe it is. You could have a finally block that eats a bunch of stack and hits the out of stack a second time. I'll give it a try and see if it is possible.

Comment: +1 for "Were I in that situation I'd prefer to fix the problem by understanding the problem before I try to fix it." I wish everyone and their manager in the industry had the same attitude.

Comment: I'ld like to understand the problem too, but the customer doesn't care so much. He prefers it is working - and I think that's understandable, too. Nevertheless, I'ld like to understand the problem anyways so I don't have to fear encountering the same problem again in the future.